# Get the character after a combination of characters in a string

Tags: vb.net

I have a string `ABC(N9KGRTLMN9(0J)M3`.

I want to return the character after `GRTLM` which is `N`. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace, and create a [`RegEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.8) object with this expression:

```
GRTLM(.)
```

Then you will be able to check the [`Matches`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8) for the expression to find your character. Depending on what you know about that string, you may be able to narrow things even further. For example:

```
GRTLM([A-Za-z])
```

or

```
GRTLM([A-Z])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regular expressions (for any reason), here's an alternative:

```
Private Function ReturnCharAfter(Source As String, after As String) As Char
    Dim i As Integer = Source.IndexOf(after)
    If i < 0 Then Return Nothing
    Return Source(i + after.Length)
End Function
```

usage:

```
Dim N As Char = ReturnCharAfter("ABC(N9KGRTLMN9(0J)M3.", "GRTLM")
```

Comment: Can you please provide me the code with regular expressions. Thanks.

Comment: @AaravHari There is example code in the Matches link in my answer.

Comment: Thank you sir very much for providing help. This is working hundred percent accurately. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AaravHari - good. Could you mark my answer as accepted then, please, as someone appears to have down voted it.  Ta

Answer (score -1):

You could use [String.Split()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_String___System_StringSplitOptions_) to get the `N`

```
Dim input = "ABC(N9KGRTLMN9(0J)M3"
Dim s = "GRTLM"
Dim n = input.Split({s}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(1)(0)
```

It splits the string into substrings using `GRTLM` as a delimiter, then returns the first character of the second array item.

Or to get the index of N

```
Dim i = input.Split({s}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0).Length + s.Length
```

It splits the string and returns the length of the first array item plus the length of the delimiter string.

But perhaps the simplest way to do it is using [String.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_)

```
Dim n = input(input.IndexOf(s) + s.Length)
Dim i = input.IndexOf(s) + s.Length
```